# Apache 2.2.21 module error in Delphi 7 (cannot load specific module into server)

Tags: apache, delphi

I created an Apache 2.2.21 module (DSO) in Delphi 7 and altered the httpd.conf file but when I restart my Apache it raises "cannot load  into server. The specified module could not be found" error. I double checked that my module (.so file) is there in apache modules folder. Here is the detail of my computer:

1. O/S : Windows 7 64bit
2. Apache: 2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r
3. Delphi 7 32 bit

I've also converted my copy of httpd2.pas as per the leonardo's blog for Apache 2.2.x version compatibility changes for Delphi 7 but still having the same problem.

Here are are the code and configuration files:

1. **httpd2.pas**:

Complete file can be found here (https://github.com/stijnsanders/xxm/blob/master/Delphi/apache/HTTPD2.pas)

2. **httpd.conf entry for my module**:

```html
LoadModule myapachews_module modules/mod_myapachews.so
<Location /rktest>
    SetHandler mod_myapachews-handler
</Location>
```

3. **myapache_ws.dpr**:

```html
library myapachews;

uses
  WebBroker,
  ApacheTwoApp,
  mMain in 'mMain.pas' {WebModule1: TWebModule};

{$R *.res}

{$E so}
{$LIBPREFIX 'mod_'}

exports
  apache_module name 'myapachews_module';

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TWebModule1, WebModule1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

4. **mMain.pas**:

```html
unit mMain;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, HTTPApp;

type
  TWebModule1 = class(TWebModule)
    procedure WebModule1WebActionItem1Action(Sender: TObject;
      Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  WebModule1: TWebModule1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1WebActionItem1Action(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Response.Content := '<H1>Hello World</H1>';
end;

end.
```

5. **mMain.dfm**:

```html
object WebModule1: TWebModule1
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Actions = <
    item
      Name = 'WebActionItem1'
      OnAction = WebModule1WebActionItem1Action
    end>
  Left = 343
  Top = 116
  Height = 292
  Width = 374
end
```

Any help or info would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Ravinder

Answer (score 0):

Though I'm honoured a link to a repository of mine ends up in here, I'm also saddened you haven't taken a look at the [xxm](http://xxm.sourceforge.net/) project since it serves exactly the purpose you're trying to achieve. It also has a Apache HTTPD handler to load xxm projects for you (and keep them portable over IIS, InternetExplorer's IInternetProtocol or a local xxmHttp for debugging).

To answer your question. On Windows, you can keep using the `.dll` file extension, there's no need to change it to `.so` which would be incorrect since the Delphi 7 compiler doesn't deliver ELF binaries. Remember to use forward slashes, or double the backslashes since these service as escape characters.

Also check the file is correctly written to Apache HTTPD's `modules` directory. Or you can use an absolute path in the httpd.conf with the `LoadModule` directive.

Comment: I apologize that couldn't go through the XXM project as I was just going through the steps mentioned in Leonardo's blog to fix the Apache 2.2.x comptibility issues. I thought it should've fixed the problem but it didn't. Well, as per your suggestions, I tried using .DLL and absolute path in httpd.conf file but still having the same issue. Is there any way to DEBUG Apache or Trace the internal error because I'm not seeing any error in my Logs\*.log file? Are you able to register this .dll/.so file?

Comment: I haven't debugged Apache httpd itself, but you can set it as a host application. Use the `-X` command line parameter to force it to use a single httpd.exe process. https://github.com/stijnsanders/xxm/blob/master/Delphi/apache/xxmAhttpd.dof#L104

Comment: After debugging and making some changes in DSO, now I'm getting the following error: "httpd: Syntax error on line 492 of C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Founda
tion/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf: API module structure 'myapachews_module' in file
 C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/modules/mod_myapach
ews.so is garbled - expected signature 41503232 but saw 41503230 - perhaps this
is not an Apache module DSO, or was compiled for a different Apache version?". I verified my httpd.pas has MODULE_MAGIC_COOKIE set to $41503232. Any idea?

Comment: I figured it out - somehow these new magic constants were not being assigned by my Delphi compiler - it was using the old files (don't know why  - even I removed the older files completely). I wanted to thank you @Stijn for all your help.